# Ant property set to files inside given directory

Tags: java, ant, build

I'm working on an ant-build script and got a given variable with the path of a directory.
I now want to get all these files inside this directory with a separator (like ';') and use it as a property.

```
<property name="connectivity.additional.jars" value="${connectivity.additional.jars.dir}" />
```

I tried it with filesets, but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach and how I would set this as a property / or even concat the filenames...

```
<fileset dir="${connectivity.additional.jars.dir}">
  <include name="**/*.jar"/>
</fileset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a fileset with id is the right approach. Use it combined with ant builtin properties `${ant.refid:filesetid}` or `${toString:filesetid}`, f.e. :

```
<project>
<fileset dir="c:/WKS/gradle-2.4/lib" id="foo">
  <include name="**/*.jar"/>
</fileset>

<property name="foobar" value="${toString:foo}"/>
<!-- or -->
<property name="foobar" value="${ant.refid:foo}"/>   
</project>
```

`${ant.refid:xxx}` or `${toString:main.xxx}` is a csv property with ';'
as default separator,  see Ant manual [Properties and PropertyHelpers](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html).